# Concentration of functions of random unitary matrices

Tags: random-matrices, measure-concentration, pr.probability

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are $n \times n$ random unitary matrices, chosen independently from the Haar measure. Is there any kind of concentration inequality which would be applicable to polynomials $p(U,V)$ in entries of $U$ and $V$? More specifically, I am interested in polynomials of the form:

$ \sum U_{ij}V_{i'j'} X_{ii'}Y_{jj'}$

or

$ |\sum U_{ij}V_{i'j'} X_{ii'}Y_{jj'}|^2$

where $X$ and $Y$ are some arbitrary matrices and the sum is over all indices. For matrices with i.i.d. Gaussian entries there are well-known concentration bounds for this kind of expressions, I would like to know if there is anything similar for unitary matrices (for this case or for $U=V$).

Comment: For some ideas, please see the comments and answer to my related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80145/expected-norm-of-sum-of-random-orthogonal-matrices